Fresh install of Ubuntu server: unable to host virtual name based websites in apache2
I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 24.04 LAMP stack.
I am having a tough time getting virtual named subdomain websites working.
Every subdomain points to the same default site file.
I followed a few suggestions offered on the site but they were for older versions of Ubuntu server.  One solution stated to use the a2dissite command to disable the default website. When I tried the command a2dissite default as stated in the solution, it states default site does not exist.
I executed the command a2dissite 00-default.conf which did not produce the error. Afterwards I ran the reload apache2 command systemctl reload apache2.
I no longer get the default page but rather the same 403 Forbidden page for the default and all subdomains.
All the virtual sites are located in the /var/www folder.
My config files, located under sites-available and showing in sites-enabled are as follows. The other sites, hkd.patersony.conf, ris.patersony.congf and jobs.patersony.conf are modified/derived version of the below file patersony.conf :
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
#Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/patersony.org"
    ServerName www.patersony.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

Oddly enough I successfully got the virtual websites working with nethserver 7 based on centOS7. Unfortunately support has ended.
I also tried the lamp stack on Debian 12. Same issue.
What am I missing?

I don't have the argument in DocumentRoot in quotes, otherwise this looks like a subset of what mine looks like.

You have an error in your config file. You are using wrong path in the DocumentRoot directive. You mentioned that all your sites are located in the /var/www/ folder, but you are using only /www/ in you config.
Replace DocumentRoot "/www/patersony.org" with DocumentRoot "/var/www/patersony.org" and restart the server with:
sudo service apache2 restart

